# Dynamic change of css class in the field

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, razor

I would like to change the color in the (td) field [change color - change / transfer to a different css class?]

**Condition:** 
The condition comes from the "if" query. if (sb == true) then nothing changes,  if (sb == false) "[else]"
then the css class in (td class="InputsForUserColor1") may change to class="InputsForUserColor1Change".

**Notes**
(td class="InputsForUserColor2") is unchanged

**My html  code (razor/C#):** 
the variable "sb" is outside "if", assumes a different value

```
 @for (int sth = 0; sth< ViewBag.sth; sth++)
{
                if (sb == true)
                {
                    varSth = "00:00";

                }
                else
                {
                   varSth = "20:00";

                }
                         @for (int sthElse = 0; sthElse< ViewBag.sthElse; sthElse++)
                          {
                                if (nr_columns == 2)
                                {
                                    <td id="td01" class="InputsForUserColor1"></td>
                                }
                                if (nr_columns == 3)
                                {
                                    <td id="td01" class="InputsForUserColor2"></td>
                                }
                          }
}
```

**My CSS code:**

```
.InputsForUserColor1, area {
    background-color: papayawhip;
    border: hidden;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: central;
}

.InputsForUserColor1Change, area {
    background-color: white;
    border: hidden;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```

personally I didn't write it because I don't know how to approach it

Comment: The code you have shown will only work on initial load of the page (rendering of the CSHTML page on server side). If the color should change while the page is displayed by the client browser, you have to use javascript (e.g. color should change if user toggles a checkbox, before form is posted back to server). Do you need to change the color only on server side?

Comment: I only need to change the color in the client's browser, on the other side I don't need information about it, I have no idea how to convert "if" to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the color should only be set once, while the page is rendered on the server:

- set the target class in a variable of the CSHMTL page (Razor C# code block with `@{}`).
- use the value of this variable (Razor `@variableName` Syntax).

  ```
  @* assume that 'sb' does not change its value inside the for loop *@
  @{ var userColor1 = sb == true ? "InputsForUserColor1" : "InputsForUserColor1Change"; }
  @for (int sth = 0; sth< ViewBag.sth; sth++) {
      @for (int sthElse = 0; sthElse< ViewBag.sthElse; sthElse++) {
          if (nr_columns == 2) {
              <td id="td01" class="@userColor1"></td>
          }
          else if (nr_columns == 3) {
              <td id="td01" class="InputsForUserColor2"></td>
          }
      }
  }
  ```

This will render the HTML with the correct class set when the page is delivered to the client browser.

This will not work if the color needs to change due to user interactions on the client (browser) side. In this case, you have to use a client script (JavaScript) to change the color dynamically. To do this, see [jQuery addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/).